# pyinstaller not working with several warnings and errors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, package, pyinstaller, importerror

I am trying to turn my script into .exe file. When I use Pyinstaller I get several warnings and errors and it does not work:

1. `193691 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent. 193691 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent. 193691 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.`
   I installed gevent package but these warnings still appear

2)`\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service`
I installed mkl-service package but this message still appears

3)`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The module is not found.`
I am using Anaconda navigator and I dont have any additional virtual environment. I have numpy 1.19.2 and Python3.8.

4. Finally I get `PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_numpy_core required by hook for module anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_numpy_core actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py:`

I tried uninstalling anaconda and numpy and reinstalling it. I tried checking Path environment variable. all with no luck.

Comment: Did you have found any solution?

Comment: No :( but I knew it was caused by matplotlib